# Loss not changing after epochs

Tags: nlp, pytorch, text-classification

I have a simple multi-layered neural network which I am training for text classification. There are 5 classes and each text belongs to only one category. I have chosen SGD optimizer and CrossEntropyLoss from PyTorch library. Given below is my training loop:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        for i, batch in enumerate(range(no_of_batches)):
            start_index = (i * batch_size)
            if ((start_index + batch_size) < X.shape[0]):
                end_index = start_index + batch_size
                X_values, y_values = convert_input_to_tensor(X, y, start_index, end_index)
            else:
                start_index = ((i-1) * batch_size) + batch_size
                X_values, y_values = convert_input_to_tensor(X, y, start_index, -1)
            outputs = model(X_values)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_values)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

The data I am training this for is features extracted from twitter texts. The model in question is a 2 layered network as given below:

```
self.linear_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features = 320, out_features = 162),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(in_features = 162, out_features = 81),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(in_features = 81, out_features = 5)
        )
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put

```
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

inside the loop to make step for every batch. Now it is outside the loop, so you update weights only once.